# Websocket DISCONNECT from server side

Tags: spring, spring-websocket

We are trying to disconnect websocket connection from server side and it seems this enhancement is done as part of https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/16893 (formerly SPR-12288). I am not able to find exactly what change we need to implement w.r.t. the same. We are using `ChannelInterceptorAdapter` to handle the requests.